# Related to current status and status date

Tags: publications, research-process, paper-submission, journal-workflow, elsevier

I had submitted a paper to Elsevier journal on 2/8/2021. While I am continuously following the paper,  it has come to my notice that the status Date is 8/8/2021 and current status is required reviews completed.

I am not getting why the status date shown is of one and half month back.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I had checked it...But I am not getting the relation between status date and current status in my case..

Answer (score 1):

> the status Date is 8/8/2021 and current status is required reviews completed.

This means that on 8 August 2021, the status of your paper changed from whatever (most probably "Under Review") to Required Reviews Completed.

Comment: Yes ...I understood  that ...but my paper was submitted on 2/8/2021 and in  only 6 days it shows required reviews completed....Isn't it's strange...

Comment: @paru you got an exceptionally fast review, which is not necessarily strange, since it can happen (e.g. if the reviewer just happens to be free).

Comment: Ok....thanks for your reply..